# F# Wsdl Provider - Handling x references a method and a type issue

Tags: f#, wsdl, type-providers

I'm using the F# Type Provider to consume a web service. All requests work with the exception of one that give me the error below

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: The XML element 'ResponseBO' from namespace 'http://com.x.xx/xsd' references a method and a type. Change the method's message name using WebMethodAttribute or change the type's root element using the XmlRootAttribute.
```

All solutions I've seen so far involve updating the webservice which is not an option for me. What is the way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Rewrite on webservice end
2. Get all files and what not, rewrite the WSDL-/XSD-files to something valid/acceptable AND something working against live servers again

Since 1. is not an option you are left with 2., and you might as well go all in and possibly drop the F# type provider, since it uses svcutil.exe below the surface, and then do it all by hand/scripting with svcutil.exe:

- getting relevant files to some storage
- then rewrite WSDL (by hand or otherwise)
- and then svcutil.exe to generate code again (or WSDL F# type provider to rewritten files)

The second point (rewrite WSDL) might possibly not be necessary/relevant depending on if you can use any of the svcutil-switches when generating code to make the code right: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx

svcutil.exe is in general a quirky piece of <s>shit</s> software, especially if the writers of the service are not taking special good care of following all advice, best practices and what not when delivering services and descriptions.

It might in fact be that the service is not totally conformant, and as such you might check that with f.i. SoapUI and if it is not entirely conformant you might have a stronger case with regards to fix the service. See https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html for more info on this part.

I am still hoping that someone will write a new WSDL type provider for F# not depending on svcutil. But then again, if the writers of svcutil.exe has a hard time to handle every wild WSDL/service description, it wont be easy to write a new type provider either so...